# Can't resolve jquery.js and popper.js error in angular project

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, components

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ke8.png)

I import .js file to component, and I add in angular.json scripts.
Why it give me this error?